# Get all possible graphs with a given number of nodes and edges (with graph-tools)

Tags: python, graph, graph-tool

I am pretty new to graph and my knowledge is near to 0.
But I need to build a model in order to get all possible graph with a given number of edges, given number of nodes and the maximum degree between each node.

So for example i want to get all graphs possibility that have 8 nodes and exactly 3 connections (edges) between each node.

I also would like to get all the possibilities as a dictionary, like so :

```
{ 1 : [2,3,4],
  2 : [5,3,1],
  3 : [6,2,7]
... and so on
```

Of course an edge cannot be connected to itself.

So far i tried to use the graph-tools library ([here](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/))

and what i tried is :

```
from graph_tool.all import *

def degree () :
    return 3,3
g = random_graph(8, degree)
a = g.get_edges([g.edge_index])
print(a)
```

Which output me :

```
[[ 0  7  0]
 [ 0  5  2]
 [ 0  2  1]
 [ 1  7 12]
 [ 1  5 14]
 [ 1  6 13]
 [ 2  3  9]
 [ 2  4 10]
 [ 2  1 11]
 [ 3  6 22]
 [ 3  0 23]
 [ 3  1 21]
 [ 4  3  3]
 [ 4  1  5]
 [ 4  0  4]
 [ 5  2 20]
 [ 5  0 19]
 [ 5  4 18]
 [ 6  7 15]
 [ 6  5 16]
 [ 6  4 17]
 [ 7  6  8]
 [ 7  3  7]
 [ 7  2  6]]
```

Can someone explain me what am i doing wrong here ? (for example why the first list is 0,7,0 (what does it means...again i am totally new to this kind of stuff))

Why is there number greater than 7 if i defined only 8 nodes ?

How can i get all the possibilities (all graphs of 8 nodes and exactly 3 connections between each nodes) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what do you try to achieve, but I wrote a code to solve a similar problem and generate data structure from random **distinct** graphs generated with graph tools library.

It might helps you to get what you need.

If you got any question, let me know.

```py
from graph_tool.all import *
import json

def isDifferentList(list1, list2):
    return list1 != list2


def isDifferentGraph(graph1, graph2):
    for k in graph1.keys():
        if isDifferentList(graph1[k], graph2[k]):
            # if all lists of connection exists, return true and stop all iterations,
            # this mean that the graph exists, so need to generate a new one
            return True
    #the graph does not exist, we can continue with the current one
    return False


def graphExists(graph, all):
    for generated in all:
        if not isDifferentGraph(graph, generated):
            return True
    return False


def generate_output_data(gr):
    gGraph = {}
    for vertex in gr.get_edges():
        vertex0 = int(vertex[0]) + 1
        vertex1 = int(vertex[1]) + 1
        if int(vertex0) not in gGraph:
            gGraph[vertex0] = []
        if vertex1 not in gGraph:
            gGraph[vertex1] = []
        gGraph[vertex0].append(vertex1)
        gGraph[vertex1].append(vertex0)
    return gGraph


def getRandomGraph():
    return generate_output_data(random_graph(VERTICES, lambda: DEGREE, directed=False))


def defineDegreeAndvertexs(vertexs, in_degree):
    global VERTICES, DEGREE
    DEGREE = in_degree
    VERTICES = vertexs


def generateNgraph(in_vertices, in_degree, n_graphs):
    #first store inputs in globals variable
    defineDegreeAndvertexs(in_vertices, in_degree)

    #generate empty list of generated uniques graphs
    all_graphs = []
    for i in range(0, n_graphs):

        #generate a new random graph and get it as a desired output data struct
        g = getRandomGraph()

        # check if this graph already exists and generate a new one as long as it already been generated
        while graphExists(g, all_graphs):
            g = getRandomGraph()

        #Write the new graph in a text file
        with open("graphs.txt", 'a+') as f:
            f.write(json.dumps(g))
            f.write("\n")

        #append the new graph in the all graph list - this list will be the input for the graphExists function
        all_graphs.append(g)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    generateNgraph(8, 3, 1500)
```

Follow the main function here and its comments to understand the whole flow.

Output :

```
{"1": [2, 7, 5], "2": [1, 7, 5], "7": [1, 2, 6], "5": [1, 3, 2], "4": [6, 3, 8], "6": [4, 7, 8], "3": [4, 5, 8], "8": [6, 3, 4]}
{"1": [8, 7, 2], "8": [1, 2, 6], "7": [1, 4, 5], "2": [1, 6, 8], "6": [2, 3, 8], "4": [7, 3, 5], "3": [4, 5, 6], "5": [4, 3, 7]}
{"1": [8, 7, 5], "8": [1, 3, 2], "7": [1, 5, 6], "5": [1, 4, 7], "2": [3, 4, 8], "3": [2, 6, 8], "4": [6, 2, 5], "6": [4, 3, 7]}
```

Where the key of each dictionary is a named vertex and the value is a list that represents the connected vertices.

This is not a real optimized code since its complexity grows with the graphs generations. It will check each graph generated for each iteration so O(n) for the complexity.

Now for you first question : how many graphs can we output with given n edges and given degree, first it might be no solution if you want all edges strictly connected. Second, it is a very complex mathematics question in my opinion.

This is what i've found so far but fo implementing this in code I let others specialists to answer this (cause I have no clue sorry).

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154941/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-possible-connected-simple-graphs-with-n-labelle

Comment: Ohhh thats not exactly answers to all my question but it realy helped me ! thank you very much for this